# Tħε Wεαk αlpħα - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, symbols

[image: Tħε Wεαk αlpħα]

Clues: [character image]
[In text bubble: #1/2, #2, #4]
[all raised to the -1 power]

Instructions: Name That Number

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ T _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Comment: Who's that hiding in the shadow? It's rot13([Bcgvzhf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimus_Prime) [CEVZR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is the

> **FINE-STRUCTURE CONSTANT**

The character in silhouette is

> Optimus Prime as mentioned in the comments.

The things he is saying are

> The index of the prime numbers (with a small modification). That is, prime #1 is 2 so that #1/2 = 1. Prime #2 = 3 and prime #4 =7.
>  So, overall we have 137 which we invert to get 1/137, the approximate value of the [fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant)

OP Edits:

> Alpha (α) is the symbol for the Fine Structure Constant. The other odd symbols in the title are the Planck Constant ħ, and the Electric Constant ε.

> Original puzzle was missing a "_" in the answer space. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Nyfb jbegu abgvat vf gung gur svar fgehpgher pbafgnag vf glcvpnyyl ercerfragrq ol $\nycun$, naq gung $\nycun = \senp{r^2}{4 \cv \inercfvyba_0 \uone p}$.  Gurer ner u-onef naq nycunf naq rcfvybaf nyy bire gur pyhr.  V ernyyl jnag gur ercrngrq hfr bs "jrnx" gb unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur jrnx ahpyrne sbepr, ohg gur svar-fgehpgher pbafgnag vf nffbpvngrq gb gur ryrpgebzntargvp sbepr, fb... \*fuehtf\*